# ORA-28000: account is locked error in expdp

Tags: database, oracle, database-schema

I'm getting `ORA-28000: account is locked` error during oracle export utility. Issuing the below command:

> expdp user/password tables=MY_TABLE directory=TABLE_EXPORT dumpfile=myexport.dmp CONTENT=DATA_ONLY COMPRESSION=ALL

I changed our database user account password and oracle export utility is not working ever since this password change. It locks the user account every time we try to run it. 
As all my other jobs are working good with the same username and password, it has nothing to do with wrong username and password in expdp command.

It looks like some configuration or password syncs are required in some database files. Has anyone got any idea of solution to this weird situation?

Comment: If it is a generic account used by multiple users, did you intimate the change in credentials to others in your team? They might have unintentionally tried the old password multiple times and thereby locking the account.

Comment: @toddlermenot It is not a generic account. Only used by our jobs. Job runs fine till a particular stage and as soon as it runs this export utility command, the account gets locked. A weird situation. Isn't it?

Comment: How is the expdp called? From shell script? If yes, how do you handle username and  password in the expdp command?

Comment: @toddlermenot Yes from a shell script. I pass username and password as parameters to the shell script. But already checked the values using basic echo command. It is taking the correct parameters and those are correct. Just for info, same shell script was working good before password change.

Comment: Oracle is too dumb to lie to you.  If the account is locked, that means that either someone is explicitly locking the account or something is repeatedly trying to log in with the wrong password which eventually causes the account to be locked.  If you are saying that other jobs are creating sessions with this account successfully while the `expdp` job is failing, that implies that your `expdp` job isn't connecting to the same account in the same database as your other jobs.

Comment: @prashant1988 I would suggest using the `sqlplus $user/$pass` command just before the `expdp` command to verify the DB login is successful. Try this instead of current `echo`. This will tell us if the problem really with `expdp` or with the password. `echo` is alright but human eyes can be deceived easily.

Answer (score 1):

Does the new password have special characters that could cause the shell script to behave differently?

May be helpful to know the account_status:
select username,account_status from dba_users;

This would tell us if the account is getting locked due to too many failed logins or is someone running "alter user account lock".

Answer (score 1):

It happens due to multiple test connection or login attempts done with wrong parameters (aka user-name or password combinations).

> Failure -Test failed: ORA-28000: the account is locked

Now, how to unlock that particular user in `Oracle`.

*A privileged user* (`system`, `sysdba`, or database administrator) *must logon to the standby and unlock the account there*.

```
ALTER USER locked_user_name ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

COMMIT;
```